# Filtering MySql database with multiple checkboxes in VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net, checkbox

I want to filter my datas which are stored in MySql database with combining multiple checkbox and textbox queries. You can find the screenshot of the form here:

SEARCH FORM:

[image]

**TABLES:**

*PROJECTS TABLE*
[image]

*DETAILS TABLE*
[image]

**PS: Only ID field in Projects table is unique!**

If user writes in any of these three textboxes than the rest of the textbox will getting empty. Currently it works fin with textboxes. I want to combine the seach criteria with the checkboxes.

Assume that user writes in TEXTBOX1 and selects FAS, VAPA and ACC from checkboxes than the result should be listed in my listview box.

Here's the codes I've come so far :

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    If TextBox1.Text = "" And TextBox2.Text = "" And TextBox3.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Bir arama kriteri girin!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "UYARI!")
        Exit Sub
    End If


        ListView1.Items.Clear()

        If TextBox1.Text <> "" Then
                Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
                Dim ad As New MySqlDataAdapter
                Dim projeadi As String = "select projects.ID, projects.PROJEADI, projects.TEKLIFFIRMA, details.ID, details.MARKA from projects INNER JOIN details ON projects.ID = details.ID WHERE PROJEADI='" & TextBox1.Text & "';"
                Dim tbl As New DataTable
                Dim i As Integer
                With cmd
                    .CommandText = projeadi
                    .Connection = con
                End With
                With ad
                    .SelectCommand = cmd
                    .Fill(tbl)
                End With

                For i = 0 To tbl.Rows.Count - 1
                    With ListView1
                        .Items.Add(tbl.Rows(i)("ID"))
                        With .Items(.Items.Count - 1).SubItems
                            .Add(tbl.Rows(i)("PROJEADI"))
                            .Add(tbl.Rows(i)("TEKLIFFIRMA"))
                            .Add(tbl.Rows(i)("MARKA"))
                        End With
                    End With
                Next

        ElseIf TextBox2.Text <> "" Then
            Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
            Dim ad As New MySqlDataAdapter
            Dim tekliffirma As String = "select projects.ID, projects.PROJEADI, projects.TEKLIFFIRMA, details.ID, details.MARKA from projects INNER JOIN details ON projects.ID = details.ID WHERE TEKLIFFIRMA='" & TextBox2.Text & "';"
            Dim tbl As New DataTable
            Dim i As Integer
            With cmd
                .CommandText = tekliffirma
                .Connection = con
            End With
            With ad
                .SelectCommand = cmd
                .Fill(tbl)
            End With

            For i = 0 To tbl.Rows.Count - 1
                With ListView1
                    .Items.Add(tbl.Rows(i)("ID"))
                    With .Items(.Items.Count - 1).SubItems
                        .Add(tbl.Rows(i)("PROJEADI"))
                        .Add(tbl.Rows(i)("TEKLIFFIRMA"))
                        .Add(tbl.Rows(i)("MARKA"))
                    End With
                End With
            Next
        ElseIf TextBox3.Text <> "" Then
            Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
            Dim ad As New MySqlDataAdapter
            Dim marka As String = "select projects.ID, projects.PROJEADI, projects.TEKLIFFIRMA, details.ID, details.MARKA from projects INNER JOIN details ON projects.ID = details.ID WHERE MARKA='" & TextBox3.Text & "';"
            Dim tbl As New DataTable
            Dim i As Integer
            With cmd
                .CommandText = marka
                .Connection = con
            End With
            With ad
                .SelectCommand = cmd
                .Fill(tbl)
            End With

            For i = 0 To tbl.Rows.Count - 1
                With ListView1
                    .Items.Add(tbl.Rows(i)("ID"))
                    With .Items(.Items.Count - 1).SubItems
                        .Add(tbl.Rows(i)("PROJEADI"))
                        .Add(tbl.Rows(i)("TEKLIFFIRMA"))
                        .Add(tbl.Rows(i)("MARKA"))
                    End With
                End With
            Next
        End If
```

Please advise.

Thank you.

Oguz

Comment: Show us the code you've so far.

Comment: I've added the codes

Comment: Ok. I can view that you're not combining the search if the user fill more than one textboxes. Is it the behavior you also want for the checkboxes?

Comment: Dear equisde. I am not allowing user to write in multiple textboxes in the same time. User only can write in one of the textboxes. Currently textbox search is working. I just need optionally combine the textbox criteria with checkboxes.

Comment: You need to write the code on `CheckBox.CheckedChanged` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since i don't know whats the name of the table field which corresponds to the checkboxes filter criteria, i'm supposing that it is `Projects.Sistem`

I would group all checkboxes into a `GroupBox` in order to use a `For` loop to check them all. If any of them is checked, an `AND` clause will be added to the end of your SQL statement.

Once done, another `For` will check every checked CheckBox to add the `Name` of the checkbox to your final SQL statement in order to obtain a SQL statement like this

```
SELECT projects.ID, projects.PROJEADI, projects.TEKLIFFIRMA, details.ID,
details.MARKA from projects INNER JOIN details ON projects.ID = details.ID
WHERE ..... AND Projects.Sistem IN ('FAS', 'VAPA', 'CCTV',.....)
```

The below code is only an approximation. You will need to check it and adapt it to your existing code

```
Dim SQL As String = ""

If projeadi <> "" Then
   SQL = projeadi
End If

If tekliffirma <> "" Then
   SQL = tekliffirma
End If

If marka <> "" Then
   SQL = marka
End If

For Each chkBox As CheckBox in GroupBox1.Controls
   If chkBox.Checked = True Then
      SQL = SQL & " AND Project.Sistem IN ( "
      Exit For
   End if
Next
For Each chkBox As CheckBox In GroupBox1.Controls
    If chkBox.Checked = True Then
         Sql = Sql & "'" & chkBox.Name & "',"
    End If
Next
Sql = Sql.Substring(0, Sql.Length - 1)
Sql = Sql & ")"
```

Comment: Dear equisde. Thank you for your answer. I've created a groupbox and bring it with default name which is GroupBox1. In the nested for loop codes it gives syntax errors for "GroupBox1" . It also gives syntax error for END FOR statement.  I am also adding the database tables screenshots in the question.

Comment: Ahhh..little typo! It should be `For Each chkBox As CheckBox in GroupBox1.Controls` and `Exit For`. Sorry, my bad! I've edited the answer.

Comment: Note: Remember to name every CheckBox according to the value of every field on `Sistem` column (E.g: Checkboxes name should be FAS, VAPA, ...  instead of CheckBox1, CheckBox2,...). Otherwise the formed SQL statement will be wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much equisde. Here's the code i've come so far. I am having a syntax problem in query. [Please Check the so far code in here](http://i58.tinypic.com/33a851t.png) I tried to check only FAS but it is adding an extra ( ,' ') in the query. [Please check the quary result in here](http://i57.tinypic.com/35bfnm0.png)

Comment: Yep. Another mistake in my code. Answer edited. Now it should construct the query without the extra `,` at the end.

Comment: Thank you again.  I think one of the "END IF" lines should be deleted in the second FOR loop.

Comment: I've just tested the last `For`. It is working fine when constructing the SQL. Please copy the last edited code.

Comment: Thank you. How can i correct the typos i've marked in [this screenshot](http://i60.tinypic.com/2m4opjk.png) ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80069/discussion-between-equisde-and-ardeth).

Comment: Dear equisde. Thank you for your regardful help. I am stucked in searching only with checkboxes. As you know i was trying to combine the search criteria with textbox1 or textbox2 or textbox3. But i forgot you to ask about what if the user only wants to search with checkboxes. Could you please advise?

Comment: Create another flag `anyTextFilled`. Set it to false when the user leave the textboxes empty. Check this flag when constructing the SQL. If this flag is set to `false` try to construct  `SELECT * FROM Projects WHERE Project.Sistem IN ('FAS', 'VAPA'...)`